# change css style on click with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following click event. I would also like to toggle the background-position: between top and bottom on click.

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.banner-inner-content').slideToggle('slow', function () {
    });
});
```

So how can i toggle between?

```
.close{background-position:top}
```

and

```
.close{background-position:bottom;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to [**`.css()`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(this).css('background-position', function(i, val) {
    return val === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top';
});
```

Or you define a new class:

```
.close.bottom {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

and use [**`.toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$(this).toggleClass('bottom');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use two differents css class (one for top and the other for bottom) and when onClick  event is shooted change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.close').click(function () {
        if($('.banner-inner-content').hasClass('top')){
            $('.banner-inner-content').removeClass('top');
            $('.banner-inner-content').addClass('bottom');
    }else{
            $('.banner-inner-content').addClass('top');
            $('.banner-inner-content').removeClass('bottom');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using isvisible to check if its being displayed or not and add the respective position:

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.banner-inner-content').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: 'top'});
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: 'bottom'});
        }
    });
});
```