# Change styles properties on iframe click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.org" frameborder="0" style="top: -100; left: -250; width: 400; height: 590; border: 0; border:none;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-controls"></iframe>
```

I want it automatically changes
to:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.org" frameborder="0" style="top: -200; left: -650; width: 950; height: 800; border: 0; border:none;" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-controls"></iframe>
```

when clicked. Precisely and basically I want to change `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` properties.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: yes it's possible with javascript and click events

Comment: @niceman you seem to be a nice man. Could you prove it by showing me how?

Comment: you just register click event like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe , the click event should change css using either jquery's `.css` (jquery is a library for javascript) or use `.style` attribute like in here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change css style on click with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348457/change-css-style-on-click-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Just Google "How to change styles in jquery"

Tip: it uses `.click()` and `.css()`

http://api.jquery.com/css/

https://api.jquery.com/click/

[jquery change style of a div on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096739/jquery-change-style-of-a-div-on-click)

Comment: This is a pretty incomplete question. At least provide a sample snippet or working code example. Don't just link off-site since those links may break eventually and the answer won't be useful anymore.

Comment: @Soviut You have a point but its not a good question really. Dont see it been popular.

Answer (score 0):

Click events are not supported by iframes.   You will have to use some "magic" to make it happen.  Basically, you need to wrap a container that can handle events to make it work.  There is actually a jQuery plugin that might help you.  It is located here:

https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery

Here is a snippet of code changing just the width of your iframe using this plugin....hope it helps.

```
<div class="iframetrack" id="iframe_red_1">
   <iframe id="theFrame" src="http://www.example.org" style="border: 0; 
      border:none; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 500px; height: 250px;" 
      frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-controls" >
   </iframe>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<script>

    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('.iframetrack iframe').iframeTracker({

            blurCallback: function () {
                $('#theFrame').css('width', '200px');
            },
            overCallback: function (element) {
                this._overId = $(element).parents('.iframe_wrap').attr('id'); // Saving the iframe wrapper id
            },
            outCallback: function (element) {
                this._overId = null; // Reset hover iframe wrapper id
            },
            _overId: null
        });

    });
```

}